# Enable both horizontal and vertical scroll in Chrome in Android with hammer.js

Tags: jquery, events, touch, hammer.js

I am using hammer.js for recognizing touch events. I want to enable both horizontal and vertical scroll in Chrome in Android. I can enable the vertical scroll with the solution suggested here:
https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/wiki/How-to-fix-Chrome-35--and-IE10--scrolling-(touch-action), with this code snippet:

```
Hammer.defaults.behavior.touchAction = 'pan-y';
```

After that, I am also creating a hammer instance on body tag to enable pan and swipe in all directions. Here is my code:

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('id_on_body');
var mc = new Hammer(myElement);
mc.get('pan').set({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL });
mc.get('swipe').set({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL });
```

But the outcome is same. Only vertical scroll is being enabled. How can I enable horizontal scroll too?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I got a situation when I used pinch and I need horizontal/vertical scroll, this is the only way I found it works in android and iphone:

```
    var mc = new Hammer.Manager(myElement, {
        touchAction: 'manipulation'
    });
    mc.add([new Hammer.Pinch()]);

    mc.on("pinchin", function (ev) {
        //code
    });
    mc.on("pinchout", function (ev) {
        //code
    });
```